# WSO2APIM: Where to put XSLT file for XSLT Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I want to use XSLT mediator in my custom sequence to transform message for an API. I have create XSLT file name "transform.xslt" and use following syntax in my sequences.

```
<xslt key="transform.xslt" source="*" />
```

My problem is, I don't know where to put the XSLT file. Do I have to put under synapse directory or have to import to carbon repository, or is there any other configuration ?

From WSO2ESB it seems there have to be some configuration in API definition but in case of WSO2 API Manager it is automatically generated and I don't want to edit the generated file.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload XSLT file as a registry resource and refer that in the XSLT mediator.

1) Save XSLT file in local registry

```
- Log on to the APIM Management Console.
- Click on "Browse" in the left "Registry" menu
- Expand the "system" tree node and then click on the "config" 
- Then click on the "Add Resource" option
- Upload the "transform.xslt" file and give the name as "transform"
- Click on the "Add" button.

You can refer uploaded xslt file in your XSLT mediator like below.

<xslt key="conf:/transform.xslt" source="*" />
```